# How to send Redis data to a third party service periodically?

Tags: lua, redis, google-bigquery

I need to build some kind of analyzing feature in my application. At the peak times, I'm expecting to receive 15K new records per second. For speed, I'm going to use Redis for writes. But written data should be formatted and send to BigQuery for OLAP somehow. What is the most efficient way to do it?

I can think of two approaches:

1. Having a separate application which is going to connect to same
   Redis instance/cluster and GET the written data periodically and
   batch inserting to BigQuery using their API.
2. Using Lua scripts to periodically send Redis keys and values to
   BigQuery.

As much as my readings and researches, Lua script seems to be a fast solution. However I don't have any experience with it and I'm not aware of limitations. For instance, can I send HTTP API calls via Lua scripts which is run by Redis? What about error handling?

*So here is the question*:

What do you recommend to achieve the needs I mentioned above?

- a) A separate app
- b) Lua script
- c) hybrid
- d) other (so, what?)

and of course, why?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the AfterShip BigQuery streamer?

- https://github.com/AfterShip/bigquery-streamer

It seems to do exactly what you need: "*This is a streamer to transport Redis records to Google BigQuery using stream insert mode.*"

Comment: Thanks for the answer Felipe. The title is absolutely what I am looking for. However, the repository looks pretty personal and I have concerns as if it is not production ready code. Have you ever used it in production?

Comment: I haven't used it, but this presentation might help http://www.slideshare.net/aftership/stream-billions-of-data-to-google-big-query

Comment: Seems like worth to try :) I'll give it a try and let you know how it went. Thanks!

Comment: I am the CEO of AfterShip, just let you know we are using this in our production site and streaming over TB of data so far to bigquery, mainly for our logging. Feel free to let us know if any problem, as the code is pretty stable so we don't see the point to update it.